# Laravel 5.1, passing my ID

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to pass an ID of a past and insert it into another database.

I got a page with shows posts like this

> /posts/{id}

. From there on i want to add a comment section, so i got my form set up like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="/posts/{{ $post->id }}/comments">
```

(When i inspect the code, it inserts the right id and the "{{ $posts->id }}" spot.

inside my routes.php i got the folling route:

```
Route::post('/posts/{post}/comments', 'CommentsController@store');
```

and inside CommentsController.php i got the following

```
    public function store(Post $post)
{
    Comment::create([

        'body' => request('body'),
        'post_id' => $post->id 
    ]);

    return back();
}
```

When ever i try to add a comment i get this error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'post_id'
>   cannot be null

When i change my code from CommentsController.php to this:

```
'post_id' => "2"
```

it works fine (but the comment will always be added at post with ID 2)
I can't seem to find out why my id wont go trough.

Anny help with this?

Comment: it should be `$post->id`, and confirm `$post` has post data.

Comment: How can i confirm it? i already tried using $post->id before asking for help. But it gave me the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public function store(Request $request, Post $post)
{

    $comment= new Comment;

    $comment->body = $request->body;

    $comment->post_id = $post->id;

    $comment->save();

    return back();
}
```

The route model binding allows you to convert the Post ID passed into the route into the actual post object in the controller method. It may even work smoother if you use a relationship between a post and a comment, like so:

```
public function store(Request $request, Post $post)
{
    $post->comments->create([
        'body' => $request->body
    ]);

    return back();
}
```

Inside `post` model

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment','post_id');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this is giving me the following error:

FatalThrowableError in CommentsController.php line 18:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: This worked! You have no idea how long i have been trying to get this. Could you please explain a bit how and why this would work and my way did not? Like where did he find the right ID?

Comment: You type hint a model POST, You need to type hint Request instead please refer https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers

Comment: @afsalc, I submitted an edit that may clarify your answer for the OP. I also added a simpler implementation.